# How to save multidimensional array with attributes to xml file

Tags: php, xml, multidimensional-array

This multidimensional array with attributes:

```
Array
(
    [EPaperPage] => Array
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [ePdfPageSize] => 1
                    [eJpegPageSize] => 0
                )

            [EDayOfPub] => Array
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [dtmCreatedDate] => 2016-02-02T14:40:01
                            [dtmLastUpdate] => 2016-02-02T14:40:01
                            [strCreatorLoginName] => sdsdt
                            [strLastUpdaterLoginName] => sdsdst
                            [nContentVersion] => 3
                        )

                    [OrigId] => Array
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [kLocationId] => 960
                                    [strPubCustId] => OND
                                    [eLogType] => 20
                                    [strDocId] => fd34c3c5-053b-45e7-bd92-66f04db013aa
                                    [nVersion] => 0
                                )

                        )
[...]
```

must be save in file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <DialogEPaperPage>
        <EPaperPage ePdfPageSize="1" eJpegPageSize="0">
            <EDayOfPub dtmCreatedDate="2016-02-02T14:40:01" dtmLastUpdate="2016-02-02T14:40:01" strCreatorLoginName="sdfsdf" [...]
```

Comment: look at the php _XMLWriter_ php class.

Comment: I tried this: http://techlister.com/php/convert-associative-arrays-into-xml-in-php/723/ and get this error: XMLWriter::startElement(): Invalid Element Name in ...

Comment: And the saved file is also not usefull:<EPaperPage><ePdfPageSize>1</ePdfPageSize> instead of <EPaperPage ePdfPageSize="1" eJpegPageSize="0">

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive function to walk through your array. Also, I would suggest you use SimpleXML library as it more simple than DOM. So generation code is:

```
<?php    
function build($value, $node) {
    if (is_array($value) == true) {
        foreach ($value as $key => $element) {
            if ($key == '@attributes') {
                foreach ($element as $n => $v) {
                    $node->addAttribute($n, $v);
                }
            } else {
                $newNode = $node->addChild($key);
                build($element, $newNode);
            }
        }
    } else {
        $node->nodeValue = $value;
    }
}

$node = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
build($test_array, $node);
$node->asXML('/tmp/filename.xml');

?>
```

For the given array:

```
$test_array = [
    "EPaperPage" => [
        "@attributes" => [
                "ePdfPageSize" => 1,
                "eJpegPageSize" => 0
        ],

        "EDayOfPub" => [
            "@attributes" => [
                    "dtmCreatedDate" => "2016-02-02T14:40:01",
                    "dtmLastUpdate" => "2016-02-02T14:40:01",
                    "strCreatorLoginName" => "sdsdt",
                    "strLastUpdaterLoginName" => "sdsdst",
                    "nContentVersion" => 3
                ],

            "OrigId" => [
                    "@attributes" => [
                            "kLocationId" => "960",
                            "strPubCustId" => "OND",
                            "eLogType" => "20",
                            "strDocId" => "fd34c3c5-053b-45e7-bd92-66f04db013aa",
                            "nVersion" => 0
                    ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

it produces following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <EPaperPage ePdfPageSize="1" eJpegPageSize="0">
        <EDayOfPub dtmCreatedDate="2016-02-02T14:40:01" dtmLastUpdate="2016-02-02T14:40:01" strCreatorLoginName="sdsdt" strLastUpdaterLoginName="sdsdst" nContentVersion="3">
            <OrigId kLocationId="960" strPubCustId="OND" eLogType="20" strDocId="fd34c3c5-053b-45e7-bd92-66f04db013aa" nVersion="0"/>
        </EDayOfPub>
    </EPaperPage>
</root>
```

Comment: Thank you. I get an error:  Call to undefined method SimpleXMLElement::setValue()

Comment: I've updated the code. It should be `$node->nodeValue = $value` instead of `$node->setValue($value)`. Sorry.

Comment: Super. Now i get only a warning: Warning: SimpleXMLElement::addAttribute() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given (on line: $node->addAttribute($n, $v);)  and the xml-file is not readable: </TypeAreaDefs><OnEPage @attributes="0"><1 nReadOrder="1" mmXBeg="0" ...> instead of: </OnEPage><OnEPage nReadOrder="1" mmXBeg="0" mmYBeg="22.800000000000001" ...>

Comment: The array from the warning looks like: Array ( [nReadOrder] => 0 [mmXBeg] => 0 [mmYBeg] => 0 [mmWidth] => 284 [mmHeight] => 8.4749999999999996 [dblRotation] => 0 [bDirectChild] => true [nPartIdx] => 1 )

Comment: The problem is, that the node „OnEPage“ more then one times exist.

Comment: You may add additional check there if the value of an attribute is an array and process it other way.

Comment: like this:
`                foreach ($element as $n => $v) {
                    if (is_array($v)) 
                    {
                    build($v, $node);
                    }
                    else
                    {  
                    $node->addAttribute($n, $v);
                    }
          `

Comment: I think, like this: foreach ($element as $n => $v) { if (is_array($v)) { foreach ($v as $sub) $node->addAttribute($n, $sub); } else { $node->addAttribute($n, $v); }

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DOMDocument` class:

```
/* Create new XML document: */
$xml = new DOMDocument( '1.0', 'utf-8' );

/* Add DialogEPaperPage child: */
$xml->appendChild( $root = $xml->createElement( 'DialogEPaperPage' ) );

/* Add EPaperPage child: */
$root->appendChild( $EPaperPage = $xml->createElement( 'EPaperPage' ) );
/* Set EPaperPage child attributes: */
$EPaperPage->setAttribute( 'ePdfPageSize', 1 );
$EPaperPage->setAttribute( 'eJpegPageSize', 0 );

/* Add EDayOfPub child: */
$EPaperPage->appendChild( $EDayOfPub = $xml->createElement( 'EDayOfPub' ) );
/* Set EDayOfPub child attributes: */
$EDayOfPub->setAttribute( 'dtmCreatedDate', '2016-02-02T14:40:01' );
$EDayOfPub->setAttribute( 'dtmLastUpdate', '2016-02-02T14:40:01' );
$EDayOfPub->setAttribute( 'strCreatorLoginName', 'sdsdt' );
$EDayOfPub->setAttribute( 'strLastUpdaterLoginName', 'sdsdt' );
$EDayOfPub->setAttribute( 'nContentVersion', '3' );

(...)

/* Set option to pretty output: */
$xml->formatOutput = True;
/* Echoes XML: */  
$xml->saveXML());
```

See more about [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

---

(Edit: corrected bug in code)

Comment: Thank you. But the input file is every time different, so i cant use this. I get the array by import: $loadfile = file_get_contents($url); $xml      = simplexml_load_string( $loadfile ); $json     = json_encode( $xml);
$options  = json_decode( $json, TRUE ); ... then I change some attributes an now i want to save it.